# Jmeter bypassing the environment variable that been set in user defined variables and running other environments in Tests

Tags: java, testing, groovy, jmeter

I have an issue with jmeter test setting that after initializing the environment as **PROD** in user defined variable and in a specific thread group I have  tests  to run on **basic** environment  & **UAT** environment only . But these tests are passing even when ran on the **PROD** environment. My question is when PROD environment are  running why are the **UAT**/**Basic** tests passing!? is there a solution to this issue?

```
 The 3 environments I have
1) env= PROD
2) env = BASIC
3) env = UAT
```

Comment: Do you have anything that checks the value of the variable in the test plan? This question is really unclear, can you reproduce the problem in a small test plan that you can share here ?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter will execute each an every [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in the Test Plan unless you limit the execution using [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)

You can conditionally execute Samplers by putting them under the If Controller and if you use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3)

```
${__jexl3("${env}"=="PROD",)}
```

the If Controller's children will be executed only if the `env` variable value is `PROD`

If you invert the condition to look like `${__jexl3("${env}"!="PROD",)}` the Samplers will be executed if `env` variable has different value:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dmitri,  the only issue with this is that when we run these test we preset the environment ! which I don't really want that to happen so without presetting PROD in Test plan is there a way around?